# SQL - condition on field value?

Tags: sql, syntax

I would like to know whether I can test some value against a condition in each returned row somehow in the query?

e.g.:
I have columns:

```
X   Y   Z
-1   1  2
2   2   -1
3   -1  3
```

I want to use avg() for all values except for -1. I CANNOT use where<> -1 as each row contains it once.

Comment: What should happen with a value such as -2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WHERE to filter away the values you don't want to include in your average, for example to include all numbers in the average except for -1:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT AVG(x) FROM table1 WHERE x >= 0) AS x,
    (SELECT AVG(y) FROM table1 WHERE y >= 0) AS y,
    (SELECT AVG(z) FROM table1 WHERE z >= 0) AS z
```

Note that if you *really* want to include all numbers except -1 as you said in your question then you should change the WHERE clause to `x <> -1` but I doubt that this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT AVG(IF(x <> -1, x, NULL)) AS avgX,
       AVG(IF(y <> -1, y, NULL)) AS avgY,
       AVG(IF(z <> -1, x, NULL)) AS avgZ
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: It might be better with `x <> -1`, etc., as your current query only allows for values greater than zero.